# Notification from the dll to the winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

I have created a C# project , and using it's dll as a reference in another Winform application and calling the functions present in the dll project.

I have a requirement that , I have to call a winform's function from that dll.
Is there any way I can register a function to my dll ?
Or any other way I am able to notify the winform application from the dll , in some condition ?

I just want to send a kind of notification from the dll to the winform application .

I will be using WCF to wrap-up the dll project .(any help ?)

Ideas/Code samples  will be much helpful.

Answer (score 5):

The mechanism used by c# for this purpose is called an **[event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)**.

You will define this event inside your dll project.
Your Winforms project will **register** to this event, and it will run a method each time the event is fired from the dll.

Comment: Thanks for the link, going through it